# Removing .php Extension from Specific URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried searching but can't find a solution that works.

I'd like to remove the .php extension and add a trailing slash from a specific URL (about.php).

For instance...

`www.example.com/about.php` should redirect to `www.example.com/about/`

and

`www.example.com/about` should redirect to `www.example.com/about/`

I've tried various `RewriteRule`s in `.htaccess` but none of them worked the way I needed them to.

The following adds the trailing slash, and I can access the page without the extention... but the `.php` version still shows up.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^about/$ about.php [END,QSA,NC]
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Just to clarify... you have already changed the URL you are linking to in your HTML source. ie. you are already linking to `/about/`?

Comment: "The following adds the trailing slash" - That code doesn't "add" anything. It _internally rewrites_ a request for `/about/` to `/about.php` (the filesystem path that handles the request).

Comment: Yes, all links go to a page with a trailing slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To externally redirect `/about.php` (and `/about` - no trailing slash) to `/about/` (for the benefit of search engines and external third parties that may have indexed/linked to the old URL) you would need to add something like the following *before* your existing rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^about(\.php)?$ /about/ [R=302,L]
```

The condition that checks against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is to ensure we only redirect direct requests and not already rewritten requests by the later rewrite. `REDIRECT_STATUS` is empty on the initial request and gets set to the HTTP status (ie. "200" on success) after the first rewrite.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches both `/about` and `/about.php` and redirects to `/about/`.

Note that this is a 302 (temporary) redirect. Only change it to a 301 (permanent) - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed it works OK. This is to avoid caching issues (301s are cached persistently by the browser). Likewise, if you have previously experimented with 301s then you will need to make sure the browser is cleared before testing.

> **UPDATE#1:** If I wanted to do this to multiple pages

If you have just two pages (as in your example/comment) then you can combine both rules into one (rather than duplicating the rule block). For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^(about|contact)(\.php)?$ /$1/ [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(about|contact)/$ $1.php [END,QSA,NC]
```

The `$1` backreference will hold either "about" or "contact" from the capturing group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

> **UPDATE#2:** ... I'm starting to add a lot of pages and I'm afraid the list will get out of control. Is there a better way to handle tons of pages... like 50+?

If all your pages are files in the document root then you could generalise the regex and essentially rewrite everything. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)(\.php)?$ /$1/ [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/$ $1.php [END,QSA,NC]
```

This is no longer "specific", as it redirects/rewrites any URL that simply "looks like" a valid request.

`\w` is the shorthand character class for any word character (ie. `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_`), to this we add the hyphen. So your URLs/filenames can only consist of those characters.

The above will match `/about/`, `/contact/`, `/something-else/` and `/foo_BAR_123/`, etc. But it won't match `/foo.jpg`, `/foo/about/` or `/foo.bar/`, etc.

If required, you could first check that the file exists before rewriting to it (or redirecting), but that is relatively *expensive* and probably not required here.

Comment: This worked perfect! If I wanted to do this to multiple pages would the following be ideal?
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^about(\.php)?$ /about/ [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^about/$ about.php [END,QSA,NC]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^contact(\.php)?$ /contact/ [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^contact/$ contact.php [END,QSA,NC]

Comment: Yes, you could do that. However, if you have just two URLs (ie. `about` and `contact`) then you can combine these into a single rule. I've updated my answer.

Comment: this solution has been working great... but I'm starting to add a lot of pages and I'm afraid the list will get out of control. Is there a better way to handle tons of pages... like 50+? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You could simply generalise the regex to match any URL that "looks like" a filename. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use index.php instead.
index page does not show up on browser address.

You can create `http://www.example.com/about/index.php` and on the browser, it will show as:

```
http://www.example.com/about/
```

If you need to redirect from `http://www.example.com/about.php` I can recommend use header `http-equiv`:

```
< meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://www.example.com/about/'" />
```

Comment: That's actually a great idea! I didn't even consider doing it this way but I think it would be better than creating a bunch of Rewrite Conditions. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I noticed is that http://www.example.com/about/ works but so does http://www.example.com/about/index.php .

Comment: A meta refresh is not an HTTP redirect and does not convey the same meaning to the user-agent. This would also mean you would need to create `/about.php` anyway!

Comment: "but so does `example.com/about/index.php`" - You would still need to implement a redirect in `.htaccess` to prevent this. (Although this is potentially just a single directive - for all URLs.)

Comment: "but I think it would be better than creating a bunch of Rewrite Conditions" - YMMV, but I would certainly go with the URL rewrites. Beyond a few files this method becomes harder to manage. Not to mention you have an increasing number of files all called `index.php` for different pages.